# Indexing documents in Solr 5 Using Tika

Tags: indexing, solr, apache-tika

Im Using solr for indexing thousands of documents, and it works perfectly.The issue comes when some documents are not well formatted or contains some special characters and it makes solr hangs or blocked on some perticular documents and it gives these errors when viewing the log :

```
Exception while processing: files document : null:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to read content Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:70)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.TikaEntityProcessor.nextRow(TikaEntityProcessor.java:165)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:244)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:476)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:515)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:415)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:330)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:233)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:417)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:481)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:462)
Caused by: org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Unexpected RuntimeException from org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser@2cc58e97
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:258)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:256)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:120)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.TikaEntityProcessor.nextRow(TikaEntityProcessor.java:159)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.handleSpecialCharacterRuns(WordExtractor.java:407)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.handleParagraph(WordExtractor.java:256)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.handleParagraph(WordExtractor.java:196)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.parse(WordExtractor.java:105)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:201)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:172)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:256)
    ... 12 more
```

i want to detect what files are causing these problems, or at least point me to some library Im missing.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Apache Tika are you using? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: thank you for you hint, it was a tike version problem i upgraded apache tika from 1.7 to 1.10and it worked. but there's another problem with 1.10 is it doesn't extract contents from documents.but apache tika 1.7 extract content from document but the problem was it hangs on some documents, and i should shutdown the server.

Comment: Apache Tika 1.10 is not the latest version, so what happens when you try actually upgrading to the latest version?

Comment: the apache tika 1.12 didn't work at all,after some testing we used some mix of apache  tika 1.10 and apache tika 1.7 libararies for extracting and indexing documents,because with apache tika 1.10 alone didn't work for extracting content.we used apache tika 1.10 of tika parse and java7 libraires and the for the rest we used apache tika 1.7

Comment: Mixing jars between Tika versions is *explicitly* not supported, all sorts of things can and will go wrong. You should upgrade *everything* to a new version - Tika jars, Tika dependencies, the lot. I'm not surprised that things don't extract when you mix'n'match jars...

Comment: for the jar mixing i did it after testing apache tika 1.10 only librairies and it didn't extract content.and when i mixed jars of apache tika 1.10 and 1.7 indexing and extracting worked.Is mixing jars of apache tika is not recommended, because it worked?? thanks.

Comment: oki here's the result of my testing using different apache tika. with tika-core-1.7 ; tika-java7-1.7 ; tika-parsers-1.7 ; tika-xmp-1.7 i have indexation problem and data extraction is blocked on perticular server. With tika-core-1.10 ; tika-java7-1.10 ; tika-parsers-1.10 ; tika-xmp-1.10 indexation works but without extraction because in can't search over cv content. With tika-core-1.7 ; tika-java7-1.10 ; tika-parsers-1.10 ; tika-xmp-1.7 indexation and extraction works. And for 1.11 and 1.12 apache tika doesn't work with solr. Thanks